# Display content of a html page in a div

Tags: jquery, html, load

I have an index.html page:

```
<body>

<ul>
    <li><a id="page" href="#">About</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="show">
</div>

</body>
```

a jQuery:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
           $("#page").click(function(){
            $('#show').load('test.html');
           }); 
         });
    </script>
```

What I need is to display content from test.html in #show div, but above code doesn't work.

---

So my question is: what did I do wrong?

PS: I'm using jQuery 1.9.1 library from link `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` and it works with other jQuery scripts.

---

EDIT:

nevermind, I used an iFrame to display other webpage/website cotent, the jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(".faq").click(function () {
    $("#loader").fadeIn(10);
    $("#content").delay(800).fadeIn(200);
    $("#mainFrame").attr("src", "http://www.wordpress.org");
});
$(".other").click(function () {
    $("#loader").fadeIn(10); 
    $("#content").delay(800).fadeIn(200);
      $("#mainFrame").attr("src", "http://www.othersite.com");
});
$("#hide").click(function () {
    $("#loader").css("display", "none"); 
    $("#content").fadeOut(200);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#mainFrame").attr("src", "about:blank");
    }, 250);
});
});
```

and HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="faq" href="#">Show</a></li>
    <li><a class="other" href="#">Show</a></li>
</ul>
<div id ="loader"></div>
<div id="content">
<input type="button" id="hide" value="hide"></button>
<iframe src="" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" id="mainFrame" name="mainFrame"></iframe></div>
```

Comment: is there any error in the console

Comment: whether the jQuery library included after or before this above script

Answer (score -1):

i normally do it like this

```
$(function() {
$('.myButton').on('click',function() {
    var path = (this).id + '.html'
    $("#myTarget").load(path);
});
});
```

just make sure you give your buttons the same id as your .php/.html files are named

Answer (score -2):

You're injecting HTML into HTML, whereas I think you want to inject plain text into HTML.  $.load won't work for this.  You should use $.ajax or something similar to get the results, then use $.text() to inject the result.

```
$("#page").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "test.html"
        success: function(data) {
            $("#show").text(data)
        }
    })
})
```